# What is the intuitive physical difference between fermions and hard-core bosons?

Tags: fermions, interactions, bosons, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-statistics

(This is a soft question.)

If we work on a discrete lattice for simplicity, then ordinary bosons are characterized by creation and annihilation operators that satisfy the canonical commutation relations

$$\begin{align}
[b_i, b_j] = [b_i^\dagger, b_j^\dagger] &= 0, \tag{1} \\
[b_i, b_j^\dagger] &= \delta_{ij}
\end{align}$$

and fermions are characterized by the canonical anticommutation relations

$$\begin{align}
\{f_i, f_j\} = \{f_i^\dagger, f_j^\dagger\} &= 0, \tag{2} \\
\{f_i, f_j^\dagger\} &= \delta_{ij},
\end{align}$$
 which lead to complete different physics at low temperatures (Pauli exclusion, Fermi surfaces instead of Bose-Einstein condensates, etc).

Physicists (especially in the theoretical condensed-matter community) often consider "hard-core" bosons as well, which have the mixed commutation relations

$$\begin{align*}
[a_i, a_j] = [a_i^\dagger, a_j^\dagger] = [a_i, a_j^\dagger] &= 0 \qquad \text{for } i \neq j, \tag{3} \\
\{a_i, a_i\} = \{a_i^\dagger, a_i^\dagger\} &= 0, \\
\{a_i, a_i^\dagger\} &= I.
\end{align*}$$

(Alternatively, we can take the usual bosonic Fock space and manually project out all of the states with multiply occupied sites.) Physically, these commutation relations describe a system of bosons with extremely strong but very short-range repulsion, which makes any state with multiple occupancy on a single site extremely energetically unfavorable. Hard-core bosons are difficult to treat analytically, because the hard-core constraint corresponds to a strong interaction so we typically can't use perturbation theory. But they're often actually the easiest of the three cases to study numerically, because local operators have a simple tensor product structure (as with ordinary bosons), and the Hilbert space for a finite system is finite-dimensional (as with fermions).

I understand the mathematical difference between fermions and hard-core bosons, which is simply reflected in the distinction between relations (2) and (3). However, I've never really had a good physical intuition for the distinction. I could put together some words like "hard-core bosons have a Pauli exclusion principle that only works in the position basis, but not in the momentum basis," but I'm not actually sure what this really means. I don't really know how to think about translationally invariant states with multiple hard-core bosons, since (I believe) such states are neither permanents nor determinants of single-particle plane-wave wavefunctions.

Is there any physical intuition that distinguishes between the behavior of fermions and hard-core bosons?

(This question is different from [Differences between hard-core boson and fermion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60168/differences-between-hard-core-boson-and-fermion), which is asking for the actual mathematical difference between the two cases, rather than the physical intuition.)

Comment: not sure if this helps, but hardcore bosons on a lattice (in any dimension) can be exactly mapped onto a system of spin-$1/2$, with the identification of $a^{\dagger}_j = S_j^{+}$. With fermions, this doesn't work as spins in different sites will commute. In 1d there is of course the non-local Jordan-Wigner transformation to overcome this, and allow the mapping. But as I said this is *non local*, and anyhow doesn't apply to higher dimensions.

Comment: The onsite anticommutation relations impose the constraint that a site is either empty or contains one particle. For $i \neq j$ the commutator/anticommutator encodes the symmetry of the many-particle wavefunction: for bosons (commutator) it is symmetric under particle exchange, and for fermions (anticommutator) it is antisymmetric.

Comment: @yu-v Strictly speaking, the Jordan-Wigner transformation applies in any dimension (just thread a string through your lattice) - it's just rarely useful in dimensions higher than 1 because it transforms local interactions into nonlocal ones. Sometimes you can get it to work in two dimensions.

Comment: so if you want, here is an option for an intuitive difference: hardcore bosons represent a spin-$1/2$ lattice with only local interactions (if the bosons do not interact non-locally), while for fermions the corresponding spin-$1/2$ lattice essentially contains non-local terms